# Event listener to grab a value in a relative element

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm trying to create an event listener to capture the **Store Name** from the first `strong` tag when a user clicks the **Get Directions** link, in order to pass the value to the GTM datalayer.

Is it a good approach to use an if statement on click to check for the `directions` class, then look for the closet `li` and then somehow drill down to the first `strong` tag?

I don't have the ability to easily alter the HTML as it's a Wordpress plugin.

```html
<li id="7245">
  <div class="store-location">
    <p>
      <strong>Store Name</strong>
      <span>Store Street</span>
      <span>Store Town</span>
      <span>Store Country</span>
    </p>

    <p class="contact-details">
      <span>
        <strong>Email</strong>: <a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com">abc@xyz.com</a>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="direction-wrap">
    19 mi
    <a class="directions" href="#">Get Directions</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

I tried creating the event listener but was unable to get the right syntax for the if statement and I don't have the knowledge of JS to know how to track the click and find the value I need to capture.

Comment: Are there other similar sets of HTML on the page that you want to do this for, or is this the only one?

Comment: The problem with not being able to alter the HTML is that the plugin is giving you invalid HTML. There's `<strong>` element isn't closed properly, and there's a following corrupt `</span>`.

Comment: Is the HTML actually corrupt? Or is it an error introduced when copying, formatting, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `e.target` from the event, and use `.closest` to get the `li`, and then use `.querySelector` to get the element you care about:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.directions')).forEach((direction) => {
    direction.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.closest('li').querySelector('p > strong').innerHTML)
    });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="7245">
    <div class="store-location">
      <p>
        <strong>Store Name</strong>
        <span>Store Street</span>
        <span>Store Town</span>
        <span>Store Country</span>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-details">
        <span
          ><strong>Email</strong>:
          <a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com">abc@xyz.com</a></span
        >
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="direction-wrap">
      19 mi
      <a class="directions" href="#">Get Directions</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="7245">
    <div class="store-location">
      <p>
        <strong>Other Store Name</strong>
        <span>Store Street</span>
        <span>Store Town</span>
        <span>Store Country</span>
      </p>

      <p class="contact-details">
        <span
          ><strong>Email</strong>:
          <a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com">abc@xyz.com</a></span
        >
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="direction-wrap">
      19 mi
      <a class="directions" href="#">Get Directions</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works but only if you actually go in and fix the corrupt HTML which the OP says they cannot do.

Comment: Hi thank you this looks like a great solution. To clarify HTML is not corrupt that was a copy error. How do I trigger this when someone clicks the link?

Comment: This code does trigger when someone clicks the link, if it's not working then you'll need to make sure that you bind the event listeners after they've been rendered, either by putting the JS right before the `</body>` tag, or wrapping the JS inside of `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  /* code goes here */
});`

Comment: Basic error. You're right. i had the script before the html.

Answer (score 0):

Since the outer `<li></li>` tag is not corrupted, you could use the 'innerHTML' attribute to get the content as a string, then search for the first appearance of `<strong>` in the string and get the value from there:

```
document.querySelector('#7245').innerHTML.split('<strong>')[1]
```

should get you the result 'Store Name'.

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

EDIT: i just realized you wanted an event handler to do this, so, borrowing from dave's excellent approach above, maybe try something like this:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.directions')).forEach((direction) => {
direction.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.closest('li').innerHTML.split('<strong>')[1])
});});
```